# How to configure a JNDI DataSource with Spring Boot & WildFly 11.0

Tags: java, spring-boot, jboss, wildfly, jndi

I want to configure a JNDI DataSource with Spring Boot & WildFly 11.0. I am currently using Postgres DB and have the datasource config under application.properties.

I know that a jndi can be created using the following in application.properties. What am I struggling is with how do I tie this up with JBoss WildFly?

a. What do I need to add/change under standalone.xml in WildFly and
b. Any changes required under Spring Boot main application class ProjectPocApiApplication

Thanks

## ProjectPocApiApplication.java

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class ProjectPocApiApplication  extends SpringBootServletInitializer{

public static void main(String[] args) {

    SpringApplication.run(ProjectPocApiApplication.class, args);
}

@Override
protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder builder) {
    return builder.sources(ProjectPocApiApplication.class);

}}
```

## pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.poc.project</groupId>
<artifactId>project-poc-api</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<name>project-poc-api</name>
<description>POC for Project Management Dashboard </description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.12.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
         </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>9.4-1206-jdbc42</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
     </dependency>
    </dependencies> 

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Answer (score 2):

I would assume you need to have below kind of configuration in datasources subsystem of standalone xml. (make sure that org.postgresql module structure exists under WildFly home directory)

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:datasources:2.0">
    <datasources>
        <datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/PostgreSQLDataSource" pool-name="PostgreSQLDataSourcePool" enabled="true" use-java-context="true">
            <connection-url>jdbc:postgresql://localhost/test</connection-url>
            <driver>postgresql</driver>
        </datasource>
        <drivers>
            <driver name="postgresql" module="org.postgresql">
                <datasource-class>org.postgresql.Driver</datasource-class>
            </driver>
        </drivers>
    </datasources>
</subsystem>
```

And i guess you can configure the datasource in main class using below approach

```
@Bean
public DataSource dataSource() 
{
  JndiDataSourceLookup dataSourceLookup = new JndiDataSourceLookup();
  DataSource dataSource = dataSourceLookup.getDataSource("java:jboss/datasources/PostgreSQLDataSource");
  return dataSource;
}
```

(Nothing really tested, just throwing it out)

Comment: Thanks for the info. Do we need to configure datasource() in the main class? What purpose does it serve?

I performed the steps mentioned here https://github.com/robsonapsilva/spring-boot-wildfly and it worked fine for me.

Comment: right, I am not sure if there any value with that configuration in case of single datasource. Usually this comes handy when working with multiple datasources.  In your case, boot loader can pick default datasource configured through 'spring.datasource' property.